# Como descargar archivos pdf mediante jquery generados en php

Tags: jquery, pdf

Estoy intentando hacer descargas de archivo de manera dinámica, para ello utilizo jquery.  Los archivos pdf los estoy generando desde php con el plugin **Html2Pdf** (eso ya lo tengo resuelto.) El asunto es que:

Tengo "tarjetas" con datos generales de usuarios. Al hacer clic en "descargar" el sistema tiene que validar:
1.- Si se tiene permiso para hacer la descarga
2.- Que el limite de descargas no haya llegando a tope.
 Si ambas condiciones son validadas se tiene que retornar un pdf generado desde php. He ahí el problema, ¿Como envío desde php un pdf para poderlo descargar desde jquery? :/

Actualmente llevo esto:

Acción de descarga con jquery:

```
$('.descargarperfilbusqueda').click(function(){
        var token = $(this).attr('id');
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("getpdfdescargar",true);
        datos.append("token",token);
        $.ajax({
            url:"../../views/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data:datos,
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(regreso){
                alert();
            }
        });
    });
```

Archivo que recibe la petición ajax.php

```
if(isset($_POST['getpdfdescargar']) && $_POST['getpdfdescargar']==true){
        $instancia = privilegiosEmpresaController();
        $band = $instancia->permisoDescargar();

        if($band==true){
            //Aquí hago las instancias a los controladores correspondientes
//y genero ro el pdf. En resumen algo así.
require_once 'views/pdftemplates/cv.php';
        $html=ob_get_clean(); 
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','es','true','UTF-8', array(15, 10, 15, 10));
        $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($html);

        ob_end_clean();

        $html2pdf->Output($path.$archivo, 'F');
        $salida =$path.$archivo;
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$archivo.'"');
        readfile($salida);
        }else{
            return flase;
        }

    }
```

La duda es: ¿En jquery (ajax) como recibo ese objeto para iniciarlizar la descarga del archivo?

**Editado**:
Publiqué una respuesta que no me está sirviendo del todo, explico: Estoy indicándole a ajax que el objeto que voy a recibir es un blob, y con el siguiente código inicio la descarga sin problema.

```
$('.descargarperfilbusqueda').click(function(){
        var token = $(this).attr('id');
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("getpdfdescargar",true);
        datos.append("token",token);
        $.ajax({
            url:"../../views/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            data:datos,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function(regreso){

                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(regreso);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'archivo.pdf';
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
        });
    });
```

Hasta ahí todo está bien, el problema es que antes de descargar el pdf necesito hacer varias validaciones,  por ejemplo: 1.- Validar el privilegio para la descarga-. 2.- Validar que el limite no haya llegado a tope, etc. Entonces el código lo tengo así:

```
$('.descargarperfilbusqueda').click(function(){
        var token = $(this).attr('id');
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("getpdfdescargar",true);
        datos.append("token",token);
        $.ajax({
            url:"../../views/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            data:datos,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function(regreso){
                alert(regreso);
                console.log(regreso);
                if(regreso===0){
                    swal({
                        title: ':(',
                        text: 'No cuentas con privilegios para realizar esta acción.',
                        button: {
                          text: "OK",
                          value: true,
                          visible: true,
                          className: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                      })
                }else if(regreso===1){
                    swal({
                        title: ':/',
                        text: 'Ocurrió un problema al intentar descargar el archivo. Por favor intenta nuevamente.',
                        button: {
                          text: "OK",
                          value: true,
                          visible: true,
                          className: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                      })
                }
                else{
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(regreso);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'archivo.pdf';
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

¿El problema?
Ajax está recibiendo un objeto blob entonces mis condiciones para mostrar los mensajes de validación no entran. Necesito recibir desde el servidor php (true, false o el string del pdf según sea el caso) y ya en jquery convertirlo a blob solo cuando este cumpla con la condición.

Nota: Este código me sirve, es decir, me genera y descarga el dpf correctamente, pero no me funcionan los mensajes de advertencia (validaciones) por obvias razones.

¿Como convierto un string a un archivo blob pdf e iniciar la descarga?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿te da algún error el código que has probado? la parte en PHP dice return flase en lugar de false. Después de arreglar eso mira en consola de tu browser a ver si sale algún error

Comment: Creo que en este caso no sirve de nada que vuelvas a Ajax con el archivo, porque desde PHP mismo puedes preparar todo para que el archivo se descargue directamente en el cliente. Sólo tienes que modificar los `header` para forzar la descarga, por ejemplo: `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");` [Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/364950/5587982). Si quieres, puedes volver luego a Ajax para indicar al usuario simplemente que el archivo se descargó con éxito...

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿No importa que desde ajax.php haga instancia a otro controladores que están en carpetas diferentes? La descarga inicia de cualquier manera? (Esa es la parte que no entiendo...)

Comment: @derloopkat Si, regresa falso cuando no se cumplen con los permisos de descarga. El código exactamente no me da error (hasta el momento), pero estoy en la duda de como recibir el archivo pdf para inicializar la descarga.

Comment: Neftalí no importa. Del lado del servidor puedes usar cuantos archivos o clases necesites estén donde estén.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy siguiendo tu recomendación. Hago toda la "magia" en cada archivo correspondiente y esto es lo que me recibe ajax https://prnt.sc/ln93vz  obviamente estoy mostrándolo con un alert, porque si lo quito simplemente no hace nada. Con eso valido que el pdf se está generando de manera correcta pero su descarga no inicia.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Viste la respuesta que puse? tengo un error. Funciona siempre y cuando se regrese el pdf, pero cuando no se cumplen las condiciones regresa verdadero o falso, al recibirlo ajax lo convierte a objeto y entonces mis condiciones ya no se cumplen. ¿Tu sabes como recibir la respuesta y en caso de que no sea veradero o falso sonvertirlo a blob objetct?  :(  Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el atributo ***download*** del tag ***a*** de html.
Por ej.:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.download = 'file.pdf';
link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

Esto tendrías que "coordinarlo" con tu código php para que una vez que generes el archivo, a través de ajax pasés parámetros para que jquery/js prepare el vínculo o directamente inicie descarga del archivo(como en el ejemplo de arriba).

Crédito:[Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691525/how-to-download-pdf-automatically-using-js)

Saludos!,

Comment: ¿Esto lo pongo dentro del response de ajax? La verdad no entendí muy bien.

Comment: Si. "Idealmente" el ajax debería controlar que el proceso terminó sin problemas y en tal caso, iniciar la descarga. O de haber algún problema, por ej. dar un aviso de que hubo un problema y se vuelva a tratar después.

Comment: Si te das cuenta mi response tiene como variable de retorno "regreso", entonces me quedaría así? var link = document.createElement('regreso');

Comment: No. En el código de ejemplo los parámetros son la url del archivo (link.href) y el nombre (link.download). Supongo que esos parámetros lo tenés antes de generar el llamado al pdf. Lo que debés esperar, al retorno del ajax, es que el pdf se generó exitosamente (y tu variable regreso sería true) o no se generó (por las razones que sea, y tu variable regreso sería false) y entonces lanzar un mensaje acorde.

Comment: Esa parte la entiendo, el problema no es ese, si no más bien como "recibir" el pdf desde el servidor. Publiqué una respuesta pero no me está sirviendo del todo, pues con ajax recibo un objeto blob que posteriormente puedo (con parte de tu código) iniciarlizar la descarga. El problema que estoy presentando es que cuando las validaciones no se cumplem (cuando se regresa false o algún error como 1,2,3 según corresponda) todo se convierte a BLOB y no están entrando las condiciones :( . Básicamente tendría que recibir el string y ya convertirlo en el "else" del final, pero no he logrado hacerlo :(

Comment: Entiendo. El problema es que estás definiendo que la respuesta es siempre - y solamente - un blob, cuando en realidad también necesitás recibir una variable con el resultado. Usualmente para ésto usarías json, donde devolverías desde el php, por ej., un objeto conteniendo tanto los datos a procesar en js como el resultado del proceso mismo. Pero como acá estás devolviendo datos binarios (de ahí que usés blob) tendrías que retornar los datos codificados en base64 y decodificarlos en js nuevamente de texto a binario.

Answer (score 0):

Al fin encontré la respuesta. Para recibir un pdf con ajax e iniciar la descarga se utiliza el parámetro:

```
xhrFields: {
         responseType: 'blob'
        },
```

En mi caso, después de hacer mis validaciones mi código completo quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.descargarperfilbusqueda').click(function(){
        var token = $(this).attr('id');
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("getpdfdescargar",true);
        datos.append("token",token);
        $.ajax({
            url:"../../views/ajax.php",
            method:"POST",
            //dataType: 'JSON',
            data:datos,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData:false,
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function(regreso){
                alert(regreso);
                console.log(regreso);
                if(regreso===0){
                    swal({
                        title: ':(',
                        text: 'No cuentas con privilegios para realizar esta acción.',
                        button: {
                          text: "OK",
                          value: true,
                          visible: true,
                          className: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                      })
                }else if(regreso===1){
                    swal({
                        title: ':/',
                        text: 'Ocurrió un problema al intentar descargar el archivo. Por favor intenta nuevamente.',
                        button: {
                          text: "OK",
                          value: true,
                          visible: true,
                          className: "btn btn-primary"
                        }
                      })
                }
                else{
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(regreso);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'archivo.pdf';
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Algo así Neftalí: **`var blob = new Blob([regreso], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = "unNombre.pdf"; //lo puedes combinar con fecha-hora
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();`**